# AWS lex slots are behaving very strange

Tags: amazon-lex, aws-lex

I'm trying to create a bot in Lex and I'm using the default one provided by the platform(BookTrip). Here when I enter some random text when I as prompted for city, it is taking anything, though it is a valid city or not.

[image]

please let me know if I'm going wrong somewhere and how can I fix this.

Thanks

Comment: you should write some validation code

Answer (score 0):

The built-in slot types are not limited to their lists.

So it is good practice to validate the slot values yourself in Lambda.

Answer (score 0):

The built-in slots have a big room to take on values that might not be valid, this happens for cities, names, emails, etc. **To avoid this is to fill out the Corresponding utterances** for each slot in the console.

An advanced way would be to attach a Lambda that gets called with the intent, then verify each slot value received to verify it matches your validation